# Linux error when installing Keras

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, keras

I am getting this strange to me error when installing Keras on an Ubuntu server:

```
Cythonizing /tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/utils.pyx
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
                 from /tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/defs.c:287:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
In file included from /tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/defs.c:287:0:
/tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hdf5.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

I've downloaded Keras repository from https://github.com/fchollet/keras, and used this command to install it:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

My Linux specifications are:

- *Distributor ID:* Ubuntu
- *Description:* Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- *Release:* 14.04
- *Codename:* trusty

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that the problem is that it expects a file named `hdf5.h` on your include path and you don't have one. Presumably you forgot to install one of the prerequisites (or the repo's author forgot to document it), most likely a library with "hdf5" in the name. (Also note that on many linux distros, libraries are split into two packages, like `hdf5` and `hdf5-dev`, so if you install from the vendor repo you will need the latter, not just the former, to get the development files.)

Comment: Fantastic, the thing I was missing was libhdf5-dev.
And I have Keras installed, thanks to you both.

Comment: For future reference: use the "code" button, not the "code snippet" button, to include things like Python code, shell script code, and output; code snippets are only for JavaScript code that you want to be runnable on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [hdf5](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdf5) package to get the headers you need.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't that obvious to me. I am not used to read Linux errors, but lessons learned. Thanks again. WORKS !!

Answer (score 2):

Real Error is :

> "In file included from /tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/defs.c:287:0:
>   /tmp/easy_install-qQggXs/h5py-2.5.0/h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
>    #include "hdf5.h" "

*This error says that header file hdf5.h is missing.*

Run the following command to install header file:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
```

Please note that to install h5py package, run following command :

```
sudo pip install h5py
```

Hope this solves your problem