# Python keras, nolearn, import error

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, theano, deep-learning

I am getting this error when I am trying to import nolearn for theano or keras.

```html
    from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
ImportError: No module named nolearn.lasagne
```

With Keras the same type.

```html
from keras.models import Sequential
ImportError: No module named keras.models
```

I taught I had this sorted by this [Linux error when installing Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985453/linux-error-when-installing-keras?noredirect=1#comment48090541_29985453) but reality was different.

Any ideas?

This is import part of program.

```
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  9 2015, 16:20:48)

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.

Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org

>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named keras
```

Comment: So your `setup.py install` worked without errors now? Then Keras should be installed. Can you do `import keras` from a Python prompt?

Comment: worked just fine after installing these hdf5 things.